# magnific-popup ajax-link stuck on loading

Tags: ajax, magnific-popup

The popup is opened, but keeps loading. I copied the code from the example page, which is working OK. 
The paths for css, js and ajax-content are ‘bonafide’.
I can't get my head around it.

http://gerardwessel.nl/swipe/index_ajaxklik.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup/magnific-popup.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
                type: 'ajax'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>ajax klik</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="ajaxtekst.html" class="simple-ajax-popup">Load content via ajax</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ajaxtekst.html file needs to be an HTML file with html, head, and body tags.

When you click on "Load content via ajax", you can see there is an error in the browser console.